# Search If Object Contains Values From Another Array

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file that looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <software>
    <name>MozillaFirefox</name>
    <version>31.3.0</version>
    <installer_location>/Mozilla/Firefox/31.3.0.exe</installer_location
  </software>
  <software>
    <name>GoogleChrome</name>
    <version>35.7</version>
    <installer_location>/Google/Chrome/35.7.msi</installer_location
  </software>
  <software>
    <name>MozillaFirefox</name>
    <version>33.4.0</version>
    <installer_location>/Mozilla/Firefox/33.4.0.exe</installer_location>
  </software>
</catalog>
```

Here is my current code:

```
#Load XML file into $catalogXML
[xml]$catalogXML = (Get-Content (C:\test.xml))

$softwareList = MozillaFirefox,GoogleChrome,Arduino

$softwareVersionsArray = $catalogXML.catalog.software
$softwareToBeInstalled = $softwareVersionsArray|Group-Object name|ForEach-Object {$_.Group[0]}
```

Which outputs this:

```
name             version      installer_location
----             -------      ------------------ 
MozillaFirefox   31.3.0       /Mozilla/Firefox/31.3.0.exe
GoogleChrome     35.7         /Google/Chrome/35.7.msi
```

What would I code to search all of the names in $softwareToBeInstalled, comparing the names to names contained in the array $softwareList, and write any software names that are contained in $softwareList but not in $softwareToBeInstalled (Arduino in my example) to another variable $missingSoftware?

Comment: `Compare-Object $softwareList $softwareToBeInstalled.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a collection which is resizeable, then check for each element if its appears on the 2nd list ( and add it if not ):

```
# items can be added to a collection
# this method creates an empty array and pass it to a collection
$missingSoftware = {""}.Invoke() 


Foreach($name in $softwareList){
# if doesnt appear
if (-not($softwareToBeInstalled.name.Contains($name))){
        # add it to the collection
        $missingSoftware.add($name)
    }
}

write $missingSoftware
```

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through the names in `$softwareToBeInstalled` and for each name check if the name is contained in your array `$softwareList`. I would probably do it like this:

```
$desiredResults = @()
$softwareToBeInstalled.name.foreach({ 
     if(!$softwareList.contains($_)){$desiredResults += $_})
})
```

Please note that depending on what type of object $softwareToBeInstalled is you may need to invoke an enumerator in order to call .foreach. You could probably also use:

```
$softwareToBeInstalled.foreach
```

Using the same code as above but reference dollarsign underscore dot name rather than dollarsign underscore.

Comment: for some reason I had to spell out dollarsign underscore in the last sentence otherwise it automatically displays italicized with the underscore truncated.